# QGIS and the identify results

Tags: qgis, identify

I have struggle understanding the following: I have a shapefile with polygons in it. Every feature has exactly two attributes (name and city). Sometimes I have two overlapping polygons, which are really identical except for the name. Now when I select the database in QGIS and I use the identify tool to see what there is, I only get one of the features. If I do the same in ArcGIS however, the identify tool shows me the two polygons.

Do I need to set some specific setting, so that the search function in QGIS is the same as in ArcGIS?

Due to several restrictions, I am forced to use QGIS 3.8.2-Zanzibar.

Comment: You shold see the attributes of both features. Did you clicked the Button "Expand Tree" in the "Identify results"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried all the suggestions here, but nothing worked.

So I restarted again, deleted all polygons which were not identified, copied them again and then saved. Now all polygons can be found via the Identify Tool.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the QGIS documentation on the [identify tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=identify#identify):

> At the bottom of the window are the `Mode` and `View` combo boxes. Mode
> defines from which layers features should be identified:
>
> **Current layer:** only features from the selected layers are identified.
> If a group is selected, features from its visible layers are
> identified. If there is no selection then only the current layer is
> identified.
>
> **Top down, stop at first:** only features from the upper visible layer.
>
> **Top down:** all features from the visible layers. The results are shown
> in the panel.
>
> **Layer selection:** opens a context menu where the user selects the layer
> to identify features from, similar to a right-click. Only the chosen
> features will be shown in the result panel.

So you want to roll with "top down".